# How to determine the limit of this sum?

Tags: calculus

I know that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{2x^5\cdot2^x}{3^x} = 0$. But what I can't figure out is how to get that answer. One of the things I tried is $\lim_{x\to\infty} 2x^5 \cdot \lim_{x\to\infty}(\dfrac{2}{3})^x$, but then you'd get $\infty \cdot 0$, and I think that is undefined. What would be a correct way to get $0$?

Comment: Perhaps take logs, and then use L'Hôpital? (I think that if you take logs first, you don't need to use L'Hôpital multiple times like Lab Bhattacharjee is suggesting, but I'm not sure.) By the way, why are you calling this a _sum_ in the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$F=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2x^5}{(3/2)^x}$$ which is of the form $\dfrac\infty\infty$

If L'Hospital's rule is allowed,
$$F=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2\cdot5x^4}{(3/2)^x\ln3/2}$$ which is again of the form $\dfrac\infty\infty$

So, we can apply L'Hospital's rule again and so on

Comment: Perhaps it'll be easier for him to take logs first. I'm not sure, but I think that if he does, he only needs to use L'Hôpital's once.

Comment: But wait - you got me thinking with your first sum. Isn't that a standard limit? $\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{n^p}{r^n} = 0 for |r| > 1$?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see, and this is the beauty of this site, many different ways could be proposed to approach the solution. So, let me propose another one.

Consider the function  $$f(x)=\dfrac{2x^5\cdot2^x}{3^x}$$ After some simplication work the derivative is $$f'(x)=\frac{2^{x+1}} {3^{x}} x^4 \left(5-x \log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)$$ which cancels for $x=\frac{5}{\log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}$. The value of the function is quite large at this point and the second derivative test confirms that it is a maximum. So, since the function is always positive, after this specific point, it continues decreasing (remember that the derivative is negative) for ever to $0^+$.

It is even easier considering $$g(x)=\log\big(f(x)\big)= \log(2)+5\log(x)+x\log \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)=\log(2)+5\log(x)-x\log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$$ $$g'(x)=\frac{5}{x}-\log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$$ Very quickly, the $\log(x)$ has vey little weight on the value of the function which almost behaves as $-x$; so, $g(x)$ decreases almost linearly when $x$ increases and goes to $-\infty$; so, $f(x)$ goes to $0^+$

Answer (score 1):

Show that $\exists$ some $x_0$ s.t. $\forall \ x>x_0 \ x^5 < (1.4)^x$. Then use squeeze theorem.